# How to prove this inequality(7)?

Tags: inequality

> Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$, prove that
>   $$4(x^6+y^6+z^6)+5(x^5y+y^5z+z^5x)\ge\dfrac{(x+y+z)^6}{27}$$

I do this sometimes, and I think this problem is very hard, I hope someone can solve. Thank you.

By this way: In china BBs: Have solve this follow equality
$$4(x^6+y^6+z^6)+5(x^5y+y^5z+z^5x)\ge 0$$
for $x,y,z\in R$
see:

http://www.aoshoo.com/bbs1/dispbbs.asp?boardid=48&id=24626&authorid=0&page=3&star=1

Comment: I think your methods was very very agly. But the same Thanks

Comment: @arbautjc: How would evil in you deal with $5(x^5y+y^5z+z^5x)$?

Comment: I hope this inequality can prove by AM-GM,or Cauchy?

Comment: $x,y$ and $z$ are positive reals, right?

Comment: I can use AM-Gm prove this$x,y,z\in R$,then $4(x^6+y^6+z^6)+5(x^5y+y^5z+z^5x)\ge 0$

Comment: yes,$x,y,z$ was reals number !

Comment: x,y,z can be negative too, I would take a CAS and expand (x+y+z)^6 with that program and then collect like terms and go from there. I suspect out of this expansion something will happen against that second expression on the left hand side. That coefficinet 5 and looking at these exponents, that has Pascal's triangle in it

Comment: Hello:Inceptio,if $x=y=z=-1,$,then $LHS=4\times3+5\times 3=27$,and $RHS=\dfrac{3^6}{27}=27$,so $LHS=RHS$,is ture!

Comment: I use the mathmatic :that's inequality is ture.

Comment: Hello:Clark,if $x=1,y=1.z=-1$.then$LHS=4\times 3+5\times(-1)=7$,and $RHS=\dfrac{(1+1-1)^6}{27}=\dfrac{1}{27}$,so$LHS\ge RHS$

Comment: Set $a=\frac xz, b=\frac yz$ (assuming $z\neq 0$).  Then it becomes a two-variable problem, as $4(a^6+b^6+1)+5(a^5b+b^5a+a)\ge \frac{(a+b+1)^6}{27}$.

Comment: @vadim123 Wouldn't it be $4(a^6+b^6+1)+5(a^5b+b^5+a) \ge \frac{(a+b+1)^6}{27}$

Answer (score 10):

The following proof is rather more computational than I'd have liked.
This seems hard to avoid, because the inequality
$$
a(x^6+y^6+z^6) + b(x^5 y + y^5 z + z^5 x)
 \geq 3(a+b) \left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^6
$$
becomes false if the coefficient ratio $b/a$ is increased from $1.25$ to
$1.33$ (try $(x,y,z) = (6,11,-10)$).  On the bright side, the technique
applies to many other such inequalities.

For $x,y,z \in {\bf R}$ let
$$
F(x,y,z) = 4(x^6+y^6+z^6) + 5(x^5 y + y^5 z + z^5 x)
 - \frac{(x+y+z)^6}{27}.
$$
We claim that $F(x,y,z) \geq 0$, with equality if and only if $x=y=z$.
By homogeneity and cyclic symmetry we may assume $x=1$ and write
$(x,y,z) = (1,1,1) + (0,c,rc)$ for some real $c,r$.
[If $y=1$ and $z\neq 1$ we can use the equivalent $(1,1,1) + (rc,0,c)$.]
Fixing $r$, we see that $F(x,y,z)$ is a sextic in $c$ with a double root
at $c=0$, so we may write
$$
F(1,1+c,1+rc) = c^2 Q_r(c)
$$
for some quartic $Q_r$.  We claim that $Q_r(c) > 0$ for all real $c$.
For any given $r$, say $r=0$, this is easy to check by observing that
$Q_r(c) > 0$ (for example $Q_0(c) > 65$)
and computing the complex roots of $Q_r$ to enough
precision to ensure that none of them is real.  Now as we vary $r$,
the roots must stay non-real as long as they are distinct (because
they vary continuously with $Q_r$, which varies continuously with $r$).
Well, the discriminant of $Q_r$ with respect to $c$ is a somewhat
complicated polynomial $P(r)$, of degree $24$, which however is still
small enough to compute all of *its* complex roots.  It turns out that
none of them is real either (the smallest imaginary parts are
about $\pm 0.11$).  Therefore $Q_r$ has distinct roots for all $r \in {\bf R}$,
and we are done.

[$P$ is a bit simpler than its degree and coefficient size indicate:
the cyclic symmetry of $F$ is inherited by $P$, which satisfies
$P(r) = r^{24} P(\frac{r-1}{r})$; NB applying the fractional linear
transformation $r \mapsto \frac{r-1}{r}$ three times returns $r$.
So we can write
$$
\frac{P(r)}{(r-r^2)^8} = P_1\Bigl(\frac{1-3r+r^3}{r-r^2}\Bigr)
$$
for some polynomial $P_1$ of degree $8$.  But this $P_1$ is still
too long to fit in a single-line formula: it is $5^3/3^9$ times
the polynomial whose coefficients (listed from leading to constant) are
65402051, 380534982, 2948475267, 8118916470, 30806414100, 47234529054,
159944730867, 165184306830, 420238105803.  Here the imaginary parts
of the roots are about $\pm 2.06$, $\pm 2.33$, $\pm 2.52$, $\pm 4.35$,
all safely far from zero.]

Comment: If $r=0$ then $Q$ has $4$ different complex roots. If $r>1234$ why the roots of $Q_r$ must stay non-real? Why does it follow from the case $r=0$? It seems to me that you should give more details. Also about $P(r)$.

Comment: I did explain this.
As $r$ moves from $0$ to (say) $1234$, the roots stay distinct
because the discrminant never vanishes; in particular they are
never real because if one complex root moved to ${\bf R}$
then its complex conjugate would move to the same point in ${\bf R}$
and two roots would coincide.  As for $P$, I don't know what more
you want me to say: I gave a formula for it as a discriminant,
and exhibited it as $(r^2-r)^8$ times a degree-$8$ polynomial 
in $(1-3r+r^3)/(r-r^2)$.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear your idea.

Answer (score 2):

Definition:
$$
f(x,y,z) = 4(x^6+y^6+z^6) + 5(x^5 y + y^5 z + z^5 x) - \frac{(x+y+z)^6}{27}
$$
We have to prove that $\;f(x,y,z) \ge 0\;$ for all $\;x,y,z \in {\bf R}$ .
For $\;x=y=z=r\;$ equality holds: $\;f(r,r,r)= 12 r^6 + 15 r^6 - (27^2 r^6)/27 = 0$ .
As has been noticed by [user64494](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/64494/user64494),
the problem is invariant for scaling the variables with a factor $t$ : if the statement is true
for $(x,y,z)$ then it is true for $(t x,t y,t z)$ as well. Meaning that, without loss of generality,
we can consider instead only *normed* solutions, with $t=1/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. That is: with $x=y=z=0$ as the only exception. Note, however, that we have already covered this case with $f(r,r,r)=0$ where $r=0$ . Therefore WLOG we can define an additional *constraint* $\,g\,$ for all $(x,y,z)$ with
$(x \ne 0) \vee (y \ne 0) \vee (z \ne 0)$ :
$$
    g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
$$
In my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510202/how-prove-this-inequality-frac2ab4-ab-frac2bc4-bc-frac2/630689#630689) to a similar question, the following key reference is mentioned:

- [Do symmetric problems have symmetric solutions?](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions)

From this reference we have (again) the following
Theorem (**The Purkiss Principle**). *Let $f$ and $g$ be symmetric functions with continuous
second derivatives in the neighborhood of a point $P = (r, \cdots, r)$. On the set where $g$
equals $g(P)$, the function $f$ will have a local maximum or minimum at $P$ except in
degenerate cases.*

The functions $\;f(x,y,z)\;$ and $\;g(x,y,z)\;$ have already been defined accordingly.
Now $\;g(r,r,r) = 3r^2 = 1$ , hence the point $P\;$ is: $(r,r,r) = (1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}\;$ and $\;f(r,r,r) = 0\;$ must be a minimum or a maximum.
It's easy to show that the first and second derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are like the examples in the paper - preceding the proof of the Theorem there; and obeying all of the Lemmas there - thus preventing any exceptions to the Purkiss principle.
First order derivatives:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c}
\partial f / \partial x \\
\partial f / \partial y \\
\partial f / \partial z \end{array} \right] (r,r,r) =
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] =
\lambda \left[ \begin{array}{c} \partial g / \partial x \\
\partial g / \partial y \\
\partial g / \partial z 
\end{array} \right] (r,r,r) = 0
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 2 r \\ 2 r \\ 2 r \end{array} \right]
$$
Second order derivatives:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\partial^2 f/\partial x^2 & \partial^2 f/\partial x \partial y & \partial^2 f/\partial x \partial z \\
\partial^2 f/\partial x \partial y & \partial^2 f/\partial y^2 & \partial^2 f/\partial y \partial z \\
\partial^2 f/\partial x \partial z & \partial^2 f/\partial y \partial z & \partial^2 f/ \partial z^2
\end{array} \right] (r,r,r) =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
130 r^4 & -64 r^4 & -64 r^4 \\
-64 r^4 & 130 r^4 & -64 r^4 \\
-64 r^4 & -64 r^4 & 130 r^4
\end{array} \right]$$
Similar structure, as required, in:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\partial^2 g/\partial x^2 & \partial^2 g /\partial x \partial y & \partial^2 g/\partial x \partial z \\
\partial^2 g/\partial x \partial y & \partial^2 g/\partial y^2 & \partial^2 g/\partial y \partial z \\
\partial^2 g/\partial x \partial z & \partial^2 g/\partial y \partial z & \partial^2 g/ \partial z^2
\end{array} \right] (r,r,r) = 
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} \right]
$$
The form of the second order derivatives matrices guarantees that $\;f(r,r,r)\;$ must be a minimum.

**Update** in response to the comment by
[David Speyer](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/448/david-speyer).
Due to the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ the whole problem can be re-formulated in spherical
coordinates: $(x,y,z)=(\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi),\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\sin(\theta))$
with $-\pi/2<\theta<+\pi/2$ and $-\pi<\phi<+\pi$ . Substitute these into $f(x,y,z)$
and make a contour plot $(\phi,\theta)$ . We have done this for $f(x,y,z) = k/3 \; , \; k = 1,\cdots\,15$ .
Darker lines correspond with larger values of $f$ . Places where $f(x,y,z) < 0.01$ are
colored $\color{red}{red}$ and the places of the minima $\;\pm 1/\sqrt{3}(1,1,1)\;$ in spherical coordinates are indicated with a $\color{blue}{blue}$ circle. We see that the circles and the red spots coincide and that the function values are uniformly decreasing in the neighborhood of these.

[image]

Comment: That verifies that $f$ has a local minimum at $(r,r,r)$, subject to the constraint. But it doesn't show that it is a global minimum.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Thanks; see my update.

Comment: Nice image! It looks like there are $6$ other local minima ($3$ modulo the antipodal map), sitting at the bulges of the roughly equatorial band in light gray. Is that right?  Many local minima are often an obstacle to easy proofs of inequalities.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: You're quite right. There are many other local minima, but none of them as deep as the two indicated (i.e. the two that we know about). In retrospect, half of the picture i.e $0 \le \phi \le \pi$ would have been sufficient as well.

Comment: Then $f(x,y,z)=0\;$ corresponds with $(\theta,\phi)=\arcsin(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{2})$ .