# How prove this inequality $\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)}\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw

let $a,b,c>0$,and such 
$a+b+c=3$,

show that
$$\dfrac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\dfrac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\dfrac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)}\ge 1$$

I think this inequality use this
$$ab\le\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$

Comment: the best I could do was this:
by AM $\ge$ HM, we have that: 

$\frac{3}{\dfrac{1}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\dfrac{1}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\dfrac{1}{(a+c)(4-ac)}} \leq \frac{(a+b)(4-ab)+(a+c)(4-ac)+(b+c)(4-bc)}{3}=(*)$
 
using $a+b+c=3$, $a+b=3-c$,$a+c=3-b$ and $c+b=3-a$ we have:

$(*)=\frac{(3-c)(4-ab)+(3-b)(4-ac)+(3-a)(4-bc)}{3}=\frac{36-3(ab+ac+bc)-4(a+b+c)+3abc}{3}=(**)$

Using $a+b+c=3$:

$(**)=\frac{24-3(ab+ac+bc)+3abc}{3} \leq \frac{24+3}{3}=9$

which gives $2/3$ instead of $1$ on the right side of the inequality, so, it's sort of close... maybe soneone can inprove that (or use HM-GM instead of HM-AM).

Comment: Since the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(3-x)(4-K/x)}$, where positive, is convex, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-c)(4-ab)}\geq\frac{3}{4-abc}\geq\frac{3}{4}$$ by the Jensen inequality.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Have you tried your inequality for $a=b=c=1$? You obtain $1/2 \geq 3/4$... And your $K$ is not fixed, it depends on $a,b,c$, which doesn't make it a constant when trying to prove that your function is convex.

Comment: @Beni Bogosel: Sorry, I forgot a factor $2$ in the LHS. The correct statement is: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2}{(3-c)(4-ab)}\geq\frac{3}{4-abc}.$$ Using the Jensen inequality is not an overplay, since we can assume $a,b,c>0,a+b+c=3,abc=K\geq 1$ and prove the inequality with these constraints, exploting the convexity of $f(x)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The function you consider is not convex on $(0,3)$ because it has a singularity at $x=k/4$ which is definitely in that interval since $K=abc \leq 1$.

Comment: @Beni Bogosel: due to the constraints, $x$ cannot be less than $k/4$ (if $a\leq k/4$ then $bc\geq 4$ then $b+c\geq 4$); this is the reason for which I wrote "$f$, when positive, is convex".

Comment: Anyway the same conclusion (LHS$\geq 3/4$) holds by $GM-HM$, as @user119459 conjectured. The main issue, here, is that we cannot provide a decent lower bound for $\sum_{cyc}f(ab)$ when $f$ is any analytic function in a neighbourhood of zero having non-negative derivatives in zero - we would be glad to state $\sum_{cyc}f(ab)\geq 3f(1)$, but if we take $a=\epsilon,b=\epsilon,c=3-2\epsilon$ we only get the trivial bound $\sum_{cyc}f(ab)\geq 3f(0).$ So, in order to prove the $\geq 1$ inequality, we must find a way to eliminate double ($ab$) or triple ($abc$) products in the LHS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a “brute-force” proof. Let us denote your sum by $S$. We may
assume without loss that $a$ is smaller than both $b$ and $c$ ; then
$a\leq 1$. Let us put $s=b+c=3-a,t=b-c$.

**Lemma** There are numbers $M,a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3$ that can be
written as polynomials in $a$, such that
$b_1,b_2,b_3$ are all nonnegative, $M$ is positive, 
$a_0=\frac{4M}{(6-s)(s^2-3s+8)},a_2=\frac{M}{2s(16-s^2)^2}$, and the identity
$M-(4-ab)(a+b)(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3)=ct^2(b_1+b_2c+b_3c^2)$ holds.

The (ugly) proof of this lemma is deferred to the end of this answer. Noticing
that when $b$ and $c$ are interchanged, $t$ becomes $-t$, and
noticing also the identity $(16-s^2)^2-4(4-bc)(16-s^2-(b-c)^2)=(b-c)^4$ (remember
that $s=b+c$), we see that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\frac{1}{(a+b)(4-ab)} &\geq& \frac{a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3}{M} \\
\frac{1}{(a+c)(4-ac)} &\geq& \frac{a_0-a_1t+a_2t^2-a_3t^3}{M} \\ 
\frac{1}{(b+c)(4-bc)} &\geq& \frac{4}{s(16-s^2)}-\frac{4}{s(16-s^2)^2}t^2 \ \\ 
\end{array}
$$

Adding up and multiplying by $2$, we see that

$$
S \geq \big(\frac{4a_0}{M}+\frac{8}{s(16-s^2)}\big)+
\big(\frac{4a_2}{M}-\frac{8}{s(16-s^2)^2}\big)t^2=
\frac{8}{(6-s)(s^2-3s+8)}+\frac{8}{s(16-s^2)}
$$

We are then done by noticing that $s\in[2,3]$ and that the RHS of this inequality can be rewritten
as

$$
1+\frac{4+(s-2)^2(2(3-s)+8)+(s-2)^3\big(\frac{3-s}{2}\big)}{s(6-s)(16-s^2)(s^2-3s+8)}
$$

Equality is reached iff $a=b=c=1$.

**Proof of lemma** Take

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
M &=& 3(((a-7)(a^2-9)(a+1))^2)(a^2-3a+4)((a^2-3a+8)^2) \\
a_1 &=& 24(((a-7)(a-3)(a+1))^2)(3a-4)(a^2-3a+4) \\
a_3 &=& (1-a)(a^8 - 14a^7 + 177a^6 - 1152a^5 + 3903a^4 - 1362a^3 - 10033a^2 + 5984a - 4416) \\
b_1 &=& (((1-a)^{10} + 26(1-a)^9 + 213(1-a)^8 + 1572(1-a)^7 + 7256(1-a)^6 + 18720(1-a)^5)a^2 + (19696(1-a)^5 + 91664(1-a)^4 + 58944(1-a)^3 + 23040(1-a)^2 + 6912(1-a))a + 6912(1-a)) \\
b_2 &=& 3a^{11} - 66a^{10} + 842a^9 - 7038a^8 + 36340a^7 - 100374a^6 + 89838a^5 + 134190a^4 - 316271a^3 + 249000a^2 - 107968a + 35328 \\
b_3 &=& a(1-a)( -2a^8 + 28a^7 - 354a^6 + 2304a^5 - 7806a^4 + 2724a^3 + 20066a^2 - 11968a + 8832) \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Yes, it's quite typical. With 90% of what one tries with answering this question, ugliness is just around the corner :-(

Answer (score 8):

[image]       [image]       [image]

**Step 1.** [Transformation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541926/converting-triangles-to-isosceles-equilateral-or-right/542684#542684).
The three dimensional problem can be re-formulated as a two dimensional problem by introducing, [**quite like here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565217/how-prove-this-inequality-a2bc4b2ca4c2ab4-leq-64/591621#591621) ,
exactly the same triangle coordinates:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} a \\ b \\ c \end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] +
\left[ \begin{array}{c} -3 \\ 3 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] x +
\left[ \begin{array}{c} -3 \\ 0 \\ 3 \end{array} \right] y
$$
Then the inequality $\;\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)}\ge 1\;$ does not so much "simplify", but anyway becomes an inequality in two
variables. And the equation $\;a + b + c = 3\;$ corresponds with a normed 2-D triangle, with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ .

**Step 2.** Visualization.
The *insides* and *outsides* of both can easily be visualized, as has been done in the above picture on the right (seen in the plane of the triangle, with a transformation rectangular $(x,y) \rightarrow$ equilateral) :

 $\color{red}{red}$ for
the edges of $\;a + b + c = 3\;$ and $\color{green}{green}$ for $\;\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)} < 1\;$ and simply white for $\;\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)} > 1\;$ .
(With a smooth function - this one is not - the isolines would look a lot "neater".)

It is seen in the same picture that the vertices of the triangle could well have been put on the curve $\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)} = 1$ . However, this would require that $x=0$ and/or $y=0$ , which is excluded by $\;b=3x,c=3y$ both $> 0$ . For the rest the triangle is seen to be on the outside of that curve , i.e. in the white area, thus establishing, at first sight, the given inequality.

**Step 3.** Triangle edges.
Due to the denominators which can be zero, *singularities* - $\color{blue}{blue}$ lines in the middle picture - are an issue with this problem. It is seen that the vertices of the triangle are located at singular spots. Without the additional requirement $a,b,c > 0$ that would have been problematic.
Indeed. Define the function:
$$
 f(a,b,c) = \frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}+\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)}
$$
And specify for the triangle coordinates along one of the edges, say $c=3y=0$ , then:
$$
  f(a=3-3x,b=3x,c=0) = \frac{2}{3[4-9(1-x)x]} + \frac{2}{12x} + \frac{2}{12(1-x)} \\ = \frac{2/27}{(x-1/2)^2+7/36} + \frac{1/6}{1/4-(x-1/2)^2}
$$
As expected, singularities are found for $x=0,1$ . The minimum function value along a triangle edge equals $22/21 > 1$ and is found for $x=1/2$ . To be certain, by differentiation we find:
$$
  f'(x) = -\frac{2(2x-1)}{27\left[(x-1/2)^2+7/36\right]^2} + \frac{2x-1}{6\left[1/4-(x-1/2)^2\right]^2} = 0
$$
From which it is immediately clear that $x=1/2\;$ is a solution. And in the neighborhood $x\approx 1/2$ : $f'(x) \approx (-2/27(36/7)^2+4^2/6)(2x-1) = 104/147(2x-1)$ which is $< 0$ for $x < 1/2$ and $> 0$ for $x > 1/2$ , hence a minimum.

**Step 4.** Triangle inside.
There is not a whole bunch of points inside the triangle where $f(a,b,c) = 1$,
because otherwise we would have seen them as green pixels. But the fact that
they are not seen is not a proof that they do not exist. So we still have to
establish, analytically, that $f(a,b,c)$ assumes no smaller values than $1$ inside the triangle.

Luck is on our path. In one of the [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627369/why-does-group-theory-not-come-in-here#comment1322332_627369)s accompanying the question 
[Why does Group Theory not come in here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627369/why-does-group-theory-not-come-in-here) a key reference is mentioned:

- [Do symmetric problems have symmetric solutions?](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions)

From this reference we have the following
Theorem (**The Purkiss Principle**). *Let $f$ and $g$ be symmetric functions with continuous
second derivatives in the neighborhood of a point $P = (r, \cdots, r)$. On the set where $g$
equals $g(P)$, the function $f$ will have a local maximum or minimum at $P$ except in
degenerate cases.*

This is precisely what we need. We have already defined the function $f(a,b,c)$ . 
Define the function $\;g(a,b,c) = a+b+c\;$ too.
Then $\;g(r,r,r) = 3r = 3\;$ hence the point $P$ is: $\;(a,b,c) = (1,1,1)\;$ and $\;f(a,b,c) = 1\;$
(which is indeed a single "green" point, at the barycenter of the triangle). This value of $f$ cannot be a maximum because we have established greater $f$ - values along the triangle edges , e.g. $f(3/2,3/2,0) = 22/21$ . So it must be a minimum.
This completes the proof.

**Update.** As a reply to the comments about whether there could perhaps exist
a minimum at a lower level than $1$ , here comes a contour plot of $\;f(a,b,c)\;$
values in the plane of the triangle at levels $\; 1 < (2^k*10+2)/(2^k*10+1) \quad , \quad k=0 , \cdots , 11$ .
Showing a rather "flat" function behaviour, though definitely *descending*
towards the middle of the triangle : the perimeters of the contours are invariably diminishing with increasing values of $\;k\;$.

[image]

Let's specify $f(a,b,c)$ for $y=x\;$ i.e. $\;a=3(1-2x) , b=3x , c=3x$ .
This is the yellow line in the contour plot on the left. Then we have:
$$
  f(x) := f(3(1-2x),3x,3x) = \frac{4}{3(1-x)(4-9x+18x^2)}+\frac{1}{3x(4-9x^2)}
$$
The graph of this function is seen on the right. As expected, there is a positive singularity at $x=0$ . Then the function decreases uniformly until it reaches its minimum $f(1/3)=1$ at the center of the triangle. After that it raises a little bit until that local maximum $f(1/2)=22/21$ in the middle of an edge. That $f(1/3)=1$ is indeed a minimum can be verified by calculating $f'(1/3) = 0$ .

Comment: A *local* minimum. There is something that is not completely clear to me: how do you exclude the existence of other stationary points (minima, indeed) inside the triangle (like $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and cyclic permutations) where the value of the function may be below one?

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(a+b)(4-ab)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(c+6)^2}{(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(c+6)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2}=\frac{441}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$882\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2.$$
Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, it's obvious that the last inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$,

which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for the extremal value of $w^3$,

which happens in te following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $c\rightarrow0^+$ and $b=3-a$.

After this substitution we obtain:
$$882-\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2=18>0;$$

2. $b=a$ and $c=3-2a$.

In this case we get $(a-1)^2(2a^3-3a^2+6a+3)\geq0$, which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Nice applying C-S.

Comment: @River Li Thank you. What do you know about $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-x_ix_{i+1}}\geq\sqrt{n(n-1)}$ for $3\leq n\leq 19$? There is a nice solution for $n=4$. What do you know about $n\geq5$?

Comment: For $n\ge 20$, it is not true. There are several disproofs for $n\ge 20$. I have SOS proofs for $n \le 14$ but it is very complicated.

Comment: It's complicated even for $n=5$?

Comment: For $n=5, 6$, there are nice proofs, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prove a slightly weaker bound by cutting down the dimension of the problem.

For any $K\in[0,3]$, define:
$$f_K(x)=\frac{2}{(3-x)(4-x(K-x))},\qquad g_K(x)=f_{K}(x)+f_{K}(K-x).$$
By differentiating with respect to $x$, we have that the minima of $g_K(x)$ over $[0,3]$ are located in $\frac{K}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+(3-K)^2}$, so
$$g_K(x) \geq g_K\left(\frac{K}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+(3-K)^2}\right)=\frac{8(6-K)}{(13-3K)^2}$$
holds over $[0,K]$. By taking $x=b,K=b+c$, $a=3-K$ follows and we have:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2}{(3-a)(4-bc)}=\frac{2}{K(4-x(K-x))}+g_K(x).\tag{1}$$
The first term in the RHS is a non-negative and convex function $h_K(x)$ on $[0,K]$ whose graphics is symmetric with respect to $x=K/2$. Since $h_K(K/2)>h_K(0)$, $h_K(x)\geq h_K(0)=\frac{1}{2K}$ follows. This gives:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2}{(3-a)(4-bc)}\geq\frac{1}{2K}+\frac{8(6-K)}{(13-3K)^2}=j(K).\tag{2}$$
$j(K)$ is a convex function over $[0,3]$, whose minimum is attained in $x=1.4638\ldots$. This gives:

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-a)(4-bc)}\geq 0.831262\ldots > \frac{4}{5}.\tag{3}$$
We can improve this to:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-a)(4-bc)}\geq h_K\left(\frac{K}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+(3-K)^2}\right)+\frac{8(6-K)}{(13-3K)^2}=\frac{4(13+9K-2K^2)}{K(13-3K)^2},\tag{4}$$
where the RHS is increasing on $[2,3]$. Since we can assume $K=(b+c)\geq 2$ without loss of generality, we have:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-a)(4-bc)}\geq\frac{46}{49}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: Quite nice. But it's possible to prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(3-a)(4-bc)}\geq 1$ , as requested: see my answer.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I don’t think your answer actually constitutes a proof because the Purkiss principle only gives a local minimum.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: How local is "local". Isn't the inside of a triangle local enough, after that elaborate visualization exercise? (Oh well, I'll take a further look at it and see if an update is necessary)

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: By the way, by AM-GM, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS}
\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{(a+b)(4-ab)}\cdot \frac{2}{(b+c)(4-bc)}\cdot\frac{2}{(a+c)(4-ac)}}.
$$
It suffices to prove that
$$216 \ge (a + b)(b + c)(c + a)(4 - ab)(4 - bc)(4 - ca). $$
This is true. However, I don't have a nice proof.

---

**Supplement to Michael Rozenberg's very nice answer**

According to Michael Rozenberg's result, it suffices to prove that
$$882\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(4-ab)(c+6)^2.\tag{1}$$

We use pqr method instead.

Let $p = a + b + c = 3, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

(1) is written as
$$2qr-24r+18 \ge 0.$$

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$$2r \cdot \sqrt{9r} - 24r + 18 \ge 0$$
or
$$6(1 - \sqrt r)(3 + 3\sqrt r - r) \ge 0$$
which is true since $0 \le r \le 1$ (by AM-GM,
$r \le (p/3)^3 = 1$).

We are done.