# Should a "good" equation divide the plane?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, soft-question, graphing-functions, plane-curves

At the question [Is there any equation for triangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/is-there-any-equation-for-triangle) (MSE) the [answer given by Henning Makholm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/is-there-any-equation-for-triangle/544587#544587) received the most upvotes.
Therefore let's define the following triangle function $H$ with (a,b,c) the vertices of the triangle and $x$ an arbitrary point in the plane (all vectors):
$$
   H(x) = \big(|x-a|+|x-b|-|a-b|\big)
          \big(|x-b|+|x-c|-|b-c|\big)
          \big(|x-c|+|x-a|-|c-a|\big)
$$
Due to the triangle equality, the outcomes between the parentheses $\big(\big)$ are always
positive or zero, hence the product $H(x)$ is always positive or zero, regardless of the
following question: is $x$ *inside* or *outside* the triangle ? The triangle function
$H(x)$ only discriminates between $H(x)=0$ at an edge or $H(x)>0$ not at an edge of the triangle.

Now take a look at a common equation describing a circle with midpoint (vector) $a$ and
radius $R$. Let $x$ be a point (vector) in the plane. Define the circle function C(x) as:
$$
   C(x) = |x-a| - R
$$
Then for points *at* the circle $C(x) = 0$, for points *inside* the circle $C(x) < 0$
and for points *outside* the circle $C(x) > 0$. The circle equation *divides the plane*.
Note. It is of course true that dividing the plane can be circumvented by proposing an equation like:
$$
   C(x) = (|x-a| - R)^2
$$
But it seems not to be quite natural to do so.
Next take a look at the common function equation $y = f(x)$ , which can also be written as:
$$ z = F(x,y) = y - f(x) = 0
$$
The (graph of the) function $y = f(x)$ divides the plane in a positive and a negative region.
And such is also the case with many common equations for straight lines, parabolas,
hyperbolas, ellipses and so on and so forth. Still another example is in [Fermat's proof for $x^3 - y^2 = 2$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142220/fermats-proof-for-x3-y2-2) :
$$
   f(x,y) = x^3 - y^2 - 2
$$
Then for example $(x,y) = (0,0) \rightarrow f(x,y) < 0$ and $(x,y) = (2,2) \rightarrow f(x,y) > 0$. The equation
divides the plane.

But Henning's triangle equation does not divide the plane. Another triangle equation has
been proposed as an answer to the abovementioned question and this equation *does* divide the plane.

**Question.** Should a "good" equation $F(x,y) = 0$ divide the plane ? Or is it just my personal bias ?

Comment: It is clear that what is meant by "good" equation is one which gives a properly embedded dimension $1$ submanifold. By a version of the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem, then, the answer is yes.

Comment: More seriously, though, does $F(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ count as a "good" equation?

Comment: To formalize "divide the plane": We have continuous $F\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ and $F^{-1}(0)=\partial F^{-1}((-\infty,0)) = \partial F^{-1}((0,\infty))$. Yes, having such an equation is nice because it is numerically less affected by rounding errors and it quickly allows to determine interior vs. exterior points (if $F$ describes a connected simple curve)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: $F(x,y) = 0$ is a circle with radius $0$ and therefore a rather complicated way of defining the origin $(0,0)$. But OK, there's nothing "wrong" with it as such.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: How about e.g. (connected) self intersecting curves?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Other equations come into mind, such as $x^2 - y^2 = 0$, giving the two straight lines $y = \pm\, x$.