# Confusion about order of operations with point-in-tetrahedron formula

Tags: inequality

I am not a math student, but I am attempting to roll my own GJK-based hit detection function. It would seem that most of the Internet that I've searchedd through chooses to either ignore or obfuscate the test case after the triangle - namely, the tetrahedral case.

I have found the following two checks on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Interior_point which appear to be straightforward - however I'm unclear on the terminology as well as the intended order of operations.

Here's the first inequality:

> Let P be any interior point of a tetrahedron of volume V for which the
>   vertices are A, B, C, and D, and for which the areas of the opposite
>   faces are Fa , Fb , Fc , and Fd. Then[17]:p.62,#1609
>
> PA {dot} F_a + PB {dot} F_b + PC {dot} F_c + PD {dot} F_d >= 9V.

Again - I am not a math major, but I read this to mean "P times (A dot the area of opposite side BCD) + P times (B dot the area of opposite side CDA)" and so on. Which I *think* is the result of the distributive property and could be rewritten as "P times ((A dot area BCD) + (B dot area CDA) + (C dot area DAB) + (D dot area ABC))". But I am not sure that's correct.

In either event, what I do not fully understand is: how can the area of a simplex be involved in a dot product calculation? Is this my misunderstanding of the notation? Is there a different order of operations intended here? So far I have been operating on the idea that dot product requires vectors, whereas I understood area to be an integer or a float. Perhaps there is a way to express area as a vector, and I just have no idea? (that feels counter-intuitive, but then again, I'm a bit out of my depth here)

Likewise, for the following interior point check:

> For vertices A, B, C, and D, interior point P, and feet J, K, L, and M
>   of the perpendiculars from P to the faces:
>
> PA+PB+PC+PD >= 3(PJ+PK+PL+PM).

First of all - I am not certain at all what is meant by "feet J K L M". What is meant by *feet*? Is it just the cross product of the triangle?

Second, if I were to plain-English this inequality, I would read it as "(P times A) + (P times B) + (P times C) + (P times D) >= 3((P times J) +...)". Or again, if I recall my distributive property correctly (not saying I do, haha), "P(A+B+C+D) >= 3(P(J+K+L+M))". Which looks *really pretty!* If only I were sure of what J K L and M actually were.

To summarize my questions:

- in the first inequality, what is the order of operations? And: If I am supposed to get the dot product of a point and the area of the opposite face, how do I do this?
- in the second inequality, what is meant by the term *feet*?
- in both inequalities: am I correctly applying the distributive property, or do I need to go back to third grade?

Finally: if this is just an "XY Problem" and I'm chasing my tail here, I would love to know about that. But, I would also appreciate gaining a better understanding of the inequalities I've posted *in addition* to being pointed at the more correct solution for my issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For the inequality $$PA \cdot F_a + PB \cdot F_b + PC \cdot F_c + PD \cdot F_c \ge 9 V$$ 
to make sense, $PA$ should be interpreted as length of line segment between $P$ and $A$. Both $PA$ and $F_a$ are real numbers and $\cdot$ is scalar multiplication.

In fact, if we let $\vec{PA}$ be the vector from $P$ to $A$ and $\vec{F}_a$ be the outward pointing normal on the face opposite to $A$ with magnitude $F_a$. One can show
$$\vec{PA} \cdot \vec{F}_a + \vec{PB} \cdot \vec{F}_b + \vec{PC} \cdot \vec{F}_c + \vec{PD} \cdot \vec{F}_d = -9V$$
where $\cdot$ now stands for vector dot product.

Comment: @achillehui Do you have a proof that the second inequality is true in general? The reference on Wikipedia points to a source that only states this inequality for tetrahedra that have equal-area faces (and doesn't give a proof of even that).

Comment: Hmm.... I think I misinterpret the definition of $J,K,L,M$. They are the projections of $P$ to the four faces. e.g $J$ is the point lying on the plane containing the face $BCD$ such that $PJ$ is perpendicular to that plane. Once again, $PA$, $PJ$ are lengths of corresponding line segments.

Comment: @mollyerin I don't have a proof for the second inequality but I suspect it is true.

Comment: It looks to me like achille hui's equality
$$
\vec{PA} \cdot \vec{F}_a + \vec{PB} \cdot \vec{F}_b + \vec{PC} \cdot \vec{F}_c + \vec{PD} \cdot \vec{F}_d = -9V
$$
is true for *every* point $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not just interior points. This means the "test" inequality
$$
PA \cdot F_a + PB \cdot F_b + PC \cdot F_c + PD \cdot F_c \ge 9 V
$$
is true at least whenever each $\vec{Px} \cdot \vec{F}_x$ is negative ($x = A,B,C,D$), so *at best* it detects whether that condition is true, which is a substantially larger tetrahedron.

Comment: Oh, is this strictly for tetrahedrons with congruent faces? (that's probably not the right term, my apologies) That won't do; GJK produces some wonky buggers via Minkowski differences and whatnot. Sounds like I should bark up a different tree (again...)

Comment: Here's the easy way to test if a point is in a tetrahedron: http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/ptintet.html

Answer (score 1):

### Inside / Outside a Linear Tetrahedron

This answer is a *straightforward generalization* of the Inside / Outside problem
in de 2-D case, for a linear triangle. The clue is provided by a Finite Element approach.

- [Is there any equation for triangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/is-there-any-equation-for-triangle/544682#544682)

Let's consider the simplest non-trivial finite element shape in 3-D, which is
a *linear tetrahedron*.

[image]

Function behaviour is approximated inside such a
tetrahedron by a *linear* interpolation between the function values at the
vertices, also called nodal points. Let $\,T,$ be such a function, and
$\,x,y,z\,$ coordinates, then:
$$
    T = A.x + B.y + C.z + D
$$
Where the constants  A, B, C, D  are yet to be determined.
Substitute $ x=x_k $ , $ y=y_k $ , $ z=z_k $ with $ k=0,1,2,3 $ .
Start with:
$$
      T_0 = A.x_0 + B.y_0 + C.z_0 + D
$$
Clearly, the first of these equations can already be used to eliminate the
constant $D$, once and forever:
$$
      T - T_0 = A.(x - x_0) + B.(y - y_0) + C.(z - z_0)
$$
Then the constants $A$ , $B$ , $C$ are determined by:
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
    T_1 - T_0 = A.(x_1 - x_0) + B.(y_1 - y_0) + C.(z_1 - z_0)   \\
    T_2 - T_0 = A.(x_2 - x_0) + B.(y_2 - y_0) + C.(z_2 - z_0)   \\
    T_3 - T_0 = A.(x_3 - x_0) + B.(y_3 - y_0) + C.(z_3 - z_0)
\end{array} $$
Three equations with three unknowns. A solution can be found:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} A \\ B \\ C \end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x_1-x_0 & y_1-y_0 & z_1-z_0 \\
                          x_2-x_0 & y_2-y_0 & z_2-z_0 \\
                          x_3-x_0 & y_3-y_0 & z_3-z_0 \end{array} \right]^{-1}
\left[ \begin{array}{c} T_1-T_0 \\ T_2-T_0 \\ T_3-T_0 \end{array} \right]
$$
It is concluded that $A,B,C$ and hence $(T-T_0)$ must be a linear expression
in the $(T_k-T_0)$:
$$
   T - T_0 = \xi.(T_1 - T_0) + \eta.(T_2 - T_0) + \zeta.(T_3 - T_0)
$$ $$ =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \xi & \eta & \zeta \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} T_1-T_0 \\ T_2-T_0 \\ T_3-T_0 \end{array} \right]
$$
$$ =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \xi & \eta & \zeta \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x_1-x_0 & y_1-y_0 & z_1-z_0 \\
                          x_2-x_0 & y_2-y_0 & z_2-z_0 \\
                          x_3-x_0 & y_3-y_0 & z_3-z_0 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} A \\ B \\ C \end{array} \right]
$$
$$ = T - T_0 =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} x-x_0 & y-y_0 & z-z_0 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} A \\ B \\ C \end{array} \right]
$$
Hence:
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
  x - x_0 = \xi .(x_1 - x_0) + \eta.(x_2 - x_0) + \zeta.(x_3 - x_0) \\
  y - y_0 = \xi .(y_1 - y_0) + \eta.(y_2 - y_0) + \zeta.(y_3 - y_0) \\
  z - z_0 = \xi .(z_1 - z_0) + \eta.(z_2 - z_0) + \zeta.(z_3 - z_0)
\end{array} $$
But also:
$$
   T - T_0 = \xi.(T_1 - T_0) + \eta.(T_2 - T_0) + \zeta.(T_3 - T_0)
$$
Therefore the *same* expression holds for the function $\,T\,$ as well as for
the coordinates $\,x,y,z$ . This is called an *isoparametric* transformation.
It is remarked without proof that the *local coordinates* $\,\xi,\eta,\zeta\,$
within a tetrahedron can be interpreted as sub-volumes, spanned by the vectors
$\,\vec{r}_k-\vec{r}_0\,$ and $\,\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0\,$ where $\,\vec{r}=(x,y,z)\,$ and
$\,k=1,2,3$ .
Reconsider the expression:
$$
   T - T_0 = \xi.(T_1 - T_0) + \eta.(T_2 - T_0) + \zeta.(T_3 - T_0)
$$
Partial differentiation to $ \xi $ , $ \eta $ , $ \zeta $ gives:
$$
\partial T / \partial \xi = T_1 - T_0 \quad ; \quad
\partial T / \partial \eta = T_2 - T_0 \quad ; \quad
\partial T / \partial \zeta = T_3 - T_0
$$
Therefore:
$$
T = T(0) + \xi \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}
+ \eta \frac{\partial T}{\partial \eta} 
+ \zeta \frac{\partial T}{\partial \zeta}
$$
This is part of a Taylor series expansion around the node $(0)$. Such Taylor series
expansions are very common in Finite Difference analysis.
Now rewrite as follows:
$$
     T = (1 - \xi - \eta - \zeta).T_0 + \xi.T_1 + \eta.T_2 + \zeta.T_3
$$
Here the functions $\,(1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)\,,\,\xi\,,\,\eta\,,\,\zeta\,$ are called the
*shape functions* of a Finite Element. Shape functions $\,N_k\,$ have the property
that they are unity in one of the nodes (k), and zero in all other nodes.
In our case:
$$
N_0 = 1-\xi-\eta-\zeta \quad ; \quad N_1 = \xi \quad ; \quad N_2 = \eta
                       \quad ; \quad N_3 = \zeta
$$
So we have two representations, which are allmost trivially equivalent:
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
  T = T_0 + \xi.(T_1 - T_0) + \eta.(T_2 - T_0) + \zeta.(T_3 - T_0) \quad
& \mbox{: Finite Difference like} \\
  T = (1 - \xi - \eta - \zeta).T_0 + \xi.T_1 + \eta.T_2 + \zeta.T_3 \quad
& \mbox{: Finite Element like}
\end{array} $$

Let's solve $\,\xi,\,\eta,\,\zeta$ from the equations, with
[Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems) :
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
  x - x_0 = \xi .(x_1 - x_0) + \eta.(x_2 - x_0) + \zeta.(x_3 - x_0) \\
  y - y_0 = \xi .(y_1 - y_0) + \eta.(y_2 - y_0) + \zeta.(y_3 - y_0) \\
  z - z_0 = \xi .(z_1 - z_0) + \eta.(z_2 - z_0) + \zeta.(z_3 - z_0)
\end{array} $$
$$
\xi = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} x-x_0 & x_2-x_0  & x_3-x_0 \\
y-y_0 &  y_2-y_0 & y_3-y_0 \\ z-z_0 & z_2-z_0 &  z_3-z_0 \end{array} \right|
/ D \\
\eta = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} x_1-x_0 & x-x_0 &  x_3-x_0 \\
y_1-y_0 &  y-y_0 & y_3-y_0 \\ z_1-z_0 & z-z_0 &  z_3-z_0 \end{array} \right|
/ D \\
\zeta = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 &  x-x_0 \\
y_1-y_0 &  y_2-y_0 & y-y_0 \\ z_1-z_0 & z_2-z_0 &  z-z_0 \end{array} \right|
/ D $$ Where: $$
D = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 &  x_3-x_0 \\
y_1-y_0 &  y_2-y_0 & y_3-y_0 \\ z_1-z_0 & z_2-z_0 &  z_3-z_0 \end{array} \right|
$$
The ***Inside / Outside* function IO of the tetrahedron** is defined as follows.
$$
\mbox{IO} =\mbox{min}(N_0,N_1,N_2,N_3) =
\mbox{min}(\xi,\,\eta,\,\zeta,\,1-\xi-\eta-\zeta)
$$ The maximum of the IO function is reached for
$\,\xi = \eta = \zeta = 1-\xi-\eta-\zeta = 1/4 $ ,
hence at the midpoint (barycenter) of the tetrahedron. If we draw straight
lines from the the midpoint towards the vertices, and further, then the whole
space is subdvided into four regions, one where IO $= \xi$ , one where IO $= \eta$ ,
one where IO $= \zeta$ , and one where IO $= 1-\xi-\eta-\zeta$ ; hope you get
the 4-D picture. The IO function is *positive for points $(x,y,z)$ inside
the tetrahedron* and negative for points $(x,y,z)$ outside the tetrahedron,
and zero for points at the boundaries. Moreover, the value of the function is sort
of a measure for the distance between $(x,y,z)$ and the barycenter.

I've taken notice of the fact that the OP has some programming experience.
So here comes a (Delphi Pascal) program snippet that is supposed
to do the mathematics:

```
program Stick;
type
  matrix = array of array of double;
  punt = record
    x,y,z : double;
  end;
  punten = array of punt;

function det(mat : matrix) : double;
{
  Determinant of 3 x 3 matrix
}
begin
  det := mat[0,0]*mat[1,1]*mat[2,2]-mat[0,0]*mat[1,2]*mat[2,1]
        -mat[1,0]*mat[0,1]*mat[2,2]+mat[1,0]*mat[0,2]*mat[2,1]
        +mat[2,0]*mat[0,1]*mat[1,2]-mat[2,0]*mat[0,2]*mat[1,1] ;
end ;

function Identical(M : matrix) : matrix;
{
  Make copy of matrix
}
var
  i,j : integer;
  S : matrix;
begin
  SetLength(S,3,3);
  for i := 0 to 2 do
    for j := 0 to 2 do
      S[i,j] := M[i,j];
  Identical := S;
end;

procedure test;
var
  T : array[0..3] of punt;
  r : punt;
  M,S : matrix;
  i : integer;
  D,xi,eta,zeta,IO : double;
begin
{ Vertices of Tetrahedron }
  for i := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    T[i].x := Random;
    T[i].y := Random;
    T[i].z := Random;
  end;
  SetLength(M,3,3);
  for i := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    M[0,i] := T[i+1].x-T[0].x; 
    M[1,i] := T[i+1].y-T[0].y; 
    M[2,i] := T[i+1].z-T[0].z; 
  end;
  D := det(M);

  SetLength(S,3,3);
  { Barycenter test }
    r.x := (T[0].x+T1.x+T[2].x+T[3].x)/4;
    r.y := (T[0].y+T1.y+T[2].y+T[3].y)/4;
    r.z := (T[0].z+T1.z+T[2].z+T[3].z)/4;
  { Point in space }
    r.x := Random;
    r.y := Random;
    r.z := Random;
    S := Identical(M);
    S[0,0] := r.x-T[0].x;
    S[1,0] := r.y-T[0].y;
    S[2,0] := r.z-T[0].z;
    xi := det(S)/D;
    S := Identical(M);
    S[0,1] := r.x-T[0].x;
    S[1,1] := r.y-T[0].y;
    S[2,1] := r.z-T[0].z;
    eta := det(S)/D;
    S := Identical(M);
    S[0,2] := r.x-T[0].x;
    S[1,2] := r.y-T[0].y;
    S[2,2] := r.z-T[0].z;
    zeta := det(S)/D;

    IO := 1-xi-eta-zeta;
    if IO > xi then IO := xi; 
    if IO > eta then IO := eta; 
    if IO > zeta then IO := zeta; 
    Writeln(IO);
    if IO > 0 then Readln; { Inside }
end;

begin
  while true do
    test;
end.
```

Output, paused at Inside hit:

```
-3.57217102952215E+0000
-3.29649515391294E-0001
-6.94579094637227E-0001
-6.02022821324288E-0001
-3.00028147738175E-0001
-4.38988084865881E-0001
-4.44247003351889E-0001
-1.10578952640585E+0001
-4.84149144259875E-0001
-8.38910075699883E-0001
-4.40603226584686E-0001
 6.93752218750558E-0003
```

**Note.** This approach is essentially not much different from establishing
whether a point is inside / outside a sphere with equation $\,R^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$ .