# Is there a single equation describing a triangle in the Cartesian plane, using only arithmetic operations? (Yes.)

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, rational-numbers, plane-geometry

> Is there a single equation describing a triangle in the Cartesian plane which includes only arithmetic operations?

The below uses the square root---but, in this case, the square root is itself may be computed using only arithmetic.

This post is in response to [Is there an equation for a triangle?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K-Jx914NcQ) by "Stand-up Maths" (2021-12-01). Therein, a single equation for a triangle in the Cartesian plane is presented (at about minute 13). However, that equation is not valid if any of the sides of the triangle are parallel to the y-axis. I present the following as an alternative. See also "[Is there any equation for triangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544559/is-there-any-equation-for-triangle)" where the questioner starts off with the concept of slope, which is undefined for "vertical" lines.

Let there be three mutually non-parallel lines $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$ in the Cartesian Plane:

$$c_1 + a_1 x + b_1 y = 0$$
$$c_2 + a_2 x + b_2 y = 0$$
$$c_3 + a_3 x + b_3 y = 0$$

respectively, $c_k, a_k, b_k \in \mathbf{Z}$ (i.e., the integers); $k \in \left\{ 1, 2, 3\right\}$

Let $P$ be an arbitrary point $(x, y); x, y \in \mathbf{Q}$ (i.e., the rational numbers).

Let $Q_1$, $Q_2$, and $Q_3$ be the quadrances ("square distances") from $P$ to lines
$l_1$, $l_2$, and $l_3$, respectively.

$P$ is on at least one of the three lines if and only if

$$Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 = 0$$

Recall that $0 \le Q_1 Q_2 Q_3$.

Let $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ be points on two lines (a.k.a., the
intersection of the two lines): $$z_1 = l_2 l_3,$$ $$z_2 = l_3 l_1,$$
$$z_3 = l_1 l_2.$$

Let triangles $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ be the triangles formed by:
$P, z_2, z_3$; $P, z_1, z_2$; and $P, z_3, z_1$; respectively. Let triangle $T$ be the
triangle formed by $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ (i.e., by $l_1$, $l_2$, and $l_3$).

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ be the quadreas ("square areas," basically) of triangles $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$.

Let $A$ be the quadrea of triangle $T$.

Then $P$ is either on triangle $T$ or in the triangular region
bounded by $T$ if and only if

$$\sqrt{A_1}
+\sqrt{A_2}
+\sqrt{A_3}
-\sqrt{A} = 0$$

(Note that the expression on the left hand side cannot be
negative. Note that each of the terms is rational.)

Then an equation of a triangle in the Cartesian Plane is:

$$Q_1 Q_2 Q_3  +
\sqrt{A_1}
+\sqrt{A_2}
+\sqrt{A_3}
-\sqrt{A} = 0$$

or

$$Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 =
\sqrt{A}
-\sqrt{A_1}
-\sqrt{A_2}
-\sqrt{A_3}$$

Either of the above equations could be expanded into an equation in $c_k$, $a_k$, $b_k$, $x$, and $y$ only and, with the exception of the square root, would include only arithmetic operations. Moreover, I claim that, under the constraints laid out above, the "$\sqrt{}$" terms are arithmetic, since there exists at least one arithmetic process for determining *exactly* the square root of any rational number.

### Addendum I: The "Is there an equation for a triangle?" equation for a triangle

In response to @Blue 's 2021-12-13 comment, "You should include the solution presented by Stand-up Maths," that solution is:

$$(\mathrm{sign}(m_1x-y)+1)(\mathrm{sign}(m_2x-y)-1)(a_1x+b_1-y)\\+(\mathrm{sign}(m_2x-y)+1)(\mathrm{sign}(m_3x-y)+1)(a_2x+b_2-y)\\+(\mathrm{sign}(m_3x-y)-1)(\mathrm{sign}(m_1x-y)-1)(a_3x+b_3-y)=0$$

(transcribed from ["Is there an equation for a triangle?" [about minute 13])](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K-Jx914NcQ&t=13m)).

Comment: You could use three > relations which determine the side of the triangle in reference to a line. Three such equations will define all the points of the triangle. >= will include the vertices and sides.

Comment: Interesting problem. You should include the solution presented by Stand-up Maths, rather than making people visit a separate site and scrub through a video. (BTW: It's possible to embed a timestamp in a YouTube URL.) In any case ... I see that the video's solution uses the "sign" function, and that the linked Math.SE question/answers use absolute value, but you only discounted them for failing to accommodate triangles with vertical side-lines. Yet, you call your solution only "close" for using a square root. You should clarify what counts as a "arithmetic operation" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using only $+-\times\div$. If you make any function using only those, you can write it in the form $\frac{p(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)}{q(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)}$ for some polynomials $p(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)$ and $q(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)$. Therefore, it is zero only where $p(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)=0$. But if a polynomial is equal to zero on a 6-dimensional hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^6$, then it has to be zero everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: I meant to limit the scope to $(x, y) \in \mathbf{Q}^2$. I have edited the post to clarify.