# Can there be a single equation for more than one equilateral polygon with the origin set at zero?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, polygons

I have been trying to make a single equation for more than one polygon by just changing the numbers that the variables represent and I can't figure out how to do so, so any help with that would be nice.

Comment: Can you show us what you mean by an equation for a polygon? Perhaps with a few examples.

Comment: Well I am looking for an equation that doesn't make just one polygon, rather multiple when a variable's input is changed, so an equation that has no one answer.

Comment: @EwanCazar, what Blitzer is asking for is some clarity on what it means to associate a polygon with an equation. The only example that comes to (my) mind is $|x|+|y|=D$, the solution set to which is a square with sides of length $\sqrt2D$. Is this the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: I know what Blitzer was asking, I myself cannot give a reasonable response to the question but the example you gave is an example of a expression with only 1 outcome I am looking for an equation that can give more than one outcome.

Comment: @EwanCazar, I just edited my comment to give a *family* of examples, indexed by the variable $D$. They are all squares, of course, in part because I can't think offhand of any simple equation for a triangle or other polygon. (One can also get families of *rhombi* from $|ax|+|by|=|c|$.)

Comment: Related: ["Is there any equation for triangle?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/544559/409). Also ["Is there a single equation describing a triangle ..."](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4331387/409) references a Stand-up Maths video on the topic. Triangles alone are complicated, so a formula for "all polygons" is quite an ask; perhaps restricting to, say, regular polygons centered at the origin would be a good start. ... In any case, please provide some context about your skill level, to help people avoid explaining things that you already understand or using techniques that you might not.

Comment: Ok this it helpful thanks.

Comment: The solutions to $z^n=1$ form a regular polygon in the complex plane with n sides.

Comment: @Blue I have completely changed my answer including now 1) it is valid for any type of regular polygon, 2) It is justified by Viviani theorem, 3) it has an interesting 3D interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a general implicit equation, valid for any *regular polygon* (same sidelengths, same angles), centered in the origin with $n$ vertices:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n \ \underbrace{|x \cos(r+ka)+y \sin(r+ka)-p|}_{d_k}=np \tag{1}$$

where

- $a:=\frac{2\pi}{n}$
- $r$ is an angular value giving the rotation angle of the figure around the origin.
- $p$ gives the overall size of the polygon.

Here is a particular case with $n=3, p=3.5, r=-1.2$:

[image]

Proof: Expression (1) is due to a generalization of **Viviani theorem** expressing the fact that the sum of distances $d_k$ from any *interior* point of a regular polygon to its sides is a certain constant. See for example [here](https://www.quora.com/If-point-P-can-be-at-any-point-inside-a-regular-polygon-and-if-DI-is-the-distance-of-P-from-the-Ith-side-of-the-polygon-how-do-you-prove-that-d1+d2+dn-constant-where-n-is-the-number-of-sides-of-the-polygon#:%7E:text=So%20we%20have%20proved%20that,the%20polygon%20to%20its%20Side.).

It is interesting to consider the surface with equation

$$z=f(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n \ |x \cos(r+ka)+y \sin(r+ka)-p|\tag{2}$$

Please note the difference between (1) and (2): the LHS is no longer restricted to value $np$.

The structure of this surface shows that $z=np$ is a limit case corresponding to a **filled** triangle, and as soon as we are on a "level set" $np+\varepsilon$, we have a triangle reduced to its sides ; a triangle ? Not really. A triangle with "chamfered" vertices... a phenomena that takes more and more importance as $z$ increases...

[image]

Remark; There are rather similar formulas for other types of shapes, for example this one gives a quarter plane that can take any position in the plane:

$$f(x,y)=|x \cos(a+c)+y \sin(a+c)|+x \cos(2a+c)+y \sin(2a+c)=b$$

See as well [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1236.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this response but I could not get this to work so can you confirm that this is correct?

Comment: Well when I put the equation in the equation nothing came up so I would like to know of you put the proper equation in.

Comment: Sorry I had found my mistake, the equation I had put in had no parentheses around it and now that I put them on the equation works.

Comment: Also could you make this an equation for equilateral polygons only

Comment: I did and I am working on it at this moment

Comment: I have seen your edit but I don't see how this answers the updated question.

Comment: So if you can rework your equation that would be quite helpful

Comment: Yes very much thanks for the help

Comment: This is very helpful your contribution is very helpful.

Comment: In fact, I have found a different formula including all polygons either with an even or an odd number of vertices (in particular the triangle).

Comment: Wow this is very interesting this helps a lot