# How to convert a right angled triangle into a equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, fractals

I want to use the Apophysis program to make a right angled sierpinski triangle into an equilateral triangle. But how can i do so? i have tried the second picture one but that is not correct.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The second picture looks close to equilateral to me. Just move the top triangle down a bit. More precisely, change $o_y$ from $0.5$ to $\sqrt3/4 \approx 0.433$.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before and
[**answered**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541926/converting-triangles-to-isosceles-equilateral-or-right/542684#542684)
before. It can be done with a transformation that comes standard with the Finite Element Method (a so-called *isoparametric transformation*). Once you have transformed the main triangle, then all of the little triangles inside the main one will be transformed accordingly.