# Parametric determinant is given, how to find a matix with lowest dimension which has the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant

Specifically, I want to find a matrix $A$ with the lowest dimension which its elements are in simplest decompositioned form and has a predefined determinant as follows:

$\det(A)=abcd-{\frac {a}{ \left( a+1 \right)  \left( d+1 \right)  \left( cd+1
 \right) }}-{\frac {b}{ \left( a+1 \right)  \left( b+1 \right)  \left( ad+1
 \right) }}-{\frac {c}{ \left( c+1 \right)  \left( b+1 \right)  \left( ab+1
 \right) }}-{\frac {d}{ \left( c+1 \right)  \left( d+1 \right)  \left( bc+1
 \right) }}$

where $abcd=1$.

Surely, the elements of matrix $A$ should be $0,1,-1,a,b,c,d,\frac {1}{ \left( a+1 \right)},\frac{1}{\left( b+1 \right)},\frac {1}{ \left( c+1 \right)},\frac{1}{\left( d+1 \right)},\frac{1}{\left( cd+1\right) },\frac{1}{\left( ad+1
 \right) }  ,\frac{1}{\left( ab+1
 \right) }  ,\frac{1}{ \left( bc+1
 \right) } $.

I asked this question to checkout if it is possible to use [hadamard's inequality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality) to show that $\det(A)\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

> In general does there an algorithmic way to make such matrix from its
> given determinant?

**Update**: This inequality which is equivalent to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016106/let-abcd-be-a-tetrahedron-of-volume-1-and-m-n-p-q-r-s-on-ab-bc-cd-da-ac-bd-s-t?noredirect=1#comment8312612_4016106) spatial geometric problem has been asked and solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4026381/algebraic-inequality-sum-fracx3xyxzxt-geq-frac12?noredirect=1&lq=1) by carlson inequality which is a special case of holder inequality, but I'm still curious about using hadamard's inequality by resolving an algorithmic method for building a matrix from its parametric determinant, so would someone know about a computer program which carryout this?

Comment: For any given $x\neq1$, the matrix of lowest rank having determinant $x$ is the $1\times 1$ matrix whose single entry is $x$. The matrix of lowest rank having determinant $1$ is the $0\times 0$ matrix. You probably want to edit the question to specify what you really wanted.

Comment: Consider diagonal matrices.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank for your hint, I took into account

Comment: Here's a related question: what's the smallest $n$ for which there is an $n\times n$ zero-one matrix with a unique expression as a sum of permutation matrices?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry ,I couldn't find the question uou mentioned, would you please send its link.

Comment: It's not a question posted to this website, it's a question that occurred to me as I thought about your question. But I left out an important detail – I want a unique expression as a sum of *five* permutation matrices.

Comment: @MasM In your $4\times 4$ matrix an element in the first row is missing.