# How to find the minimum value of this function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How to find the minimum value of 
$$\frac{x}{3y^2+3z^2+3yz+1}+\frac{y}{3x^2+3z^2+3xz+1}+\frac{z}{3x^2+3y^2+3xy+1}$$,where $x,y,z\geq 0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

It seems to be hard if we use calculus methods. Are there another method? I have no idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is again a question of the symmetric type, such as listed in:

- [Why does Group Theory not come in here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627369/why-does-group-theory-not-come-in-here)

With a constraint $\;x+y+z=1\;$ and $\;x,y,z > 0$ . Sort of a general method to transform such a constraint into the inside of a triangle in 2-D has been explained at length in:

- [How prove this inequality $(a^2+bc^4)(b^2+ca^4)(c^2+ab^4) \leq 64$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565217/how-prove-this-inequality-a2bc4b2ca4c2ab4-leq-64/591621#591621)

The above preliminaries are completed with:

- [Do symmetric problems have symmetric solutions?](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/do-symmetric-problems-have-symmetric-solutions)

From the latter article comes the following
Theorem (**The Purkiss Principle**). *Let $f$ and $g$ be symmetric functions with continuous second derivatives in the neighborhood of a point $P = (r, \cdots, r)$. On the set where $g$ equals $g(P)$, the function $f$ will have a local maximum or minimum at $P$ except in degenerate cases.*

[image]

- Picture on the left: geometry of the conditions $\;x,y,z > 0\;$ and $\;x+y+z=1$ .
- Picture on the right: contour lines of $f(x,y,z)$ , as seen in the plane of the $\color{red}{red}$ triangle, are at $20$ equidistant levels, between the minimum and the maximum as found within the viewport

Our function $f$ in this case is:
$$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{3y^2+3z^2+3yz+1}+\frac{y}{3x^2+3z^2+3xz+1}+\frac{z}{3x^2+3y^2+3xy+1} $$
Applying the Purkiss Principle gives:
$$ g(r,r,r)=r+r+r=1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad r=\frac{1}{3} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(r,r,r) = \frac{1}{2} $$
The main problem with the Purkiss Principle, most of the time, is to prove that the extreme found is global.
Or at least global enough , i.e. an absolute extreme *inside* our ($\color{red}{red}$) triangle.
In our case, the function will become less than $1/2$, namely close to zero, for $\;|x|,|y|,|z|\rightarrow \infty$ .
So it's clear that the Purkiss Principle is "violated", outside the triangle at least.
These regions, where $\;f(x,y,z)\;$ is less than, say, $1/2 + 0.001$ , are colored $\color{blue}{blue}$ in the picture on the right.
The $\color{blue}{blue\, spot}$ in the picture on the right is a *proof without words* that the only minimum *inside* the triangle is (indeed $= 1/2$ ) and at its center $(x,y,z) = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$ . This finishing touch is thus an *informal proof* (: disclaimer).

**Update** : a few further details.

- Function values close to viewport minimum are white
- Function values close to viewport maximum are black
- Contour grey values are just the other way around
- Function values at the corners of the triangle $=1$ (black)
- Function values at the edge centers of the triangle $=4/7$

Answer (score 4):

To find a minimum of the function I'm going to find a lower bound and show that the lower bound is attained. For that I'm going to use nothing harder than Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Let $f(x, y, z)$ denote your function. Using mentioned Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get:
$$f(x, y, z)\cdot\big(x(3y^2+3z^2+3yz+1) + y(3x^2+3z^2+3xz+1) + z(3x^2+3y^2+3xy+1)\big) \\
\geqslant (x+y+z)^2 = 1.$$

So,
$$f(x, y, z) \geqslant \frac{1}{3(xy^2 + xz^2 + yx^2 + yz^2 + zx^2 + zy^2 + 3xyz) + x+y+z} \\
=\frac{1}{3(x+y+z)(xy+yz+xz) + 1} = \frac{1}{3(xy+yz+xz) + 1}$$

We want to get an upper bound of $xy + yz + xz$ under the condition $x + y + z = 1$. We can do this, for example:
$$\begin{align}
xy + yz + xz &\leqslant x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\
3(xy + yz + xz) &\leqslant (x + y + z)^2 = 1 \\
xy + yz + xz &\leqslant \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Finally,
$f(x, y, z) \geqslant \dfrac{1}{3\cdot\frac{1}{3} + 1} = \dfrac{1}{2}.$ So $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is the lower bound.
Since $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$, we can see that we've found a point where the lower bound is attained so this is the minimum of the function.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ This is not hard using calculus methods, you can use Lagrange Multipliers.

In a nutshell it says that, to find the maximum and minimum value for $f(x,y,z)$ subject to $g(x,y,z)=k$ you find all $x,y,z$ and $\lambda$ such that:

$$\begin{cases} \nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y,z) \\g(x,y,z) = k \end{cases}$$

Then you evaluate $f$ in such points, the maximum value you get is the maximum value for the function, the minimum value you get is the minimum value for the function.

Remember that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (f_x,f_y,f_z)$.

Almost always the "tricky" part in problems involving Lagrange Multipliers is to solve the above system, which seems not to be the case in this example.

Comment: Remember you also have the constraints $x,y,z\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I used wolfram alpha: http://goo.gl/Cjzigc

[image]

Looks like the min is at $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$.

Comment: At $x=y=z=\dfrac{1}{3}$, the value is smaller.

Comment: Oops, I took the maxima for minima. Thanks Mark McClure for editing.

Comment: Using Wolfram Alpha is overkill. Symmetry says (c.f. Purkiss Principle) that $x=y=z=1/3\;$ gives the minimum $=1/2$ .

Answer (score 1):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3y^2+3z^2+3yz+1}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3y^2+3z^2+3yz+(x+y+z)^2}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2+4z^2+2xy+2xz+5yz}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{x^3+4xy^2+4xz^2+2x^2y+2x^2z+5xyz}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3+6x^2y+6x^2z+5xyz)}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2x^3+6x^2y+6x^2z+4xyz)}=$$
$$=\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2(x+y+z)^3}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$, which says that the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Done!