# Generalized inequality with parameters $\alpha, \beta$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $\alpha, \beta$ be positive real numbers such that $\alpha+\beta=1$. Consider the inequality in $k$ variables $x_1, x_2, …, x_k$,

$$
\alpha \cdot \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^d + \beta \cdot \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^{d-1}x_{i+1} \geq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i)^d}{k^{d-1}}
$$

In the above, $x_{k+1} = x_1$.

Question is, for what values of $(\alpha, \beta)$ does this inequality hold for all $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

This is a generalization of [How to prove this inequality(7)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343886/how-to-prove-this-inequality7)

Comment: Help! As if the non-generalization isn't hard enough!